# Do I have a complete HTTP header to authenticate properly

Tags: javascript, curl, django-rest-framework

Building a Django Rest Framework. when I user 'curl' to call the API with a valid token it works:

```
curl -viL -H "Authorization: Token 65c38dfe0c910b727197683aebdcc1c67c1b7aa3" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/habit/
```

The same API call via my javascript call, fails and Django see it as an anonymous user and errors out.

```
fetchHabits: function() {
  console.log('Token '+this.authToken.token);
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/habit/?format=json',{
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': 'Token '+this.authToken.token
     }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => this.habits = json)
},
```

I have proven that the right token is sent and received. I am assuming because CURL works that the Django code is working, so that the bug is in the header on the Javascript side.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: if you use a tool like Fiddler you can examine both requests and spot any differences in the requests, likewise any differences in the responses. What actual error do you get back? 401, 403, I guess?

Comment: No I am getting a 500, because Django sees it as an Anonymous user and throws up. I thought it was a Django issue all day yesterday until CURL worked first time. So now I am assuming I am composing the HEADER incorrectly.

Comment: ok, I'd have thought the framework would think it was a permissions error and return a permissions-related code. But maybe it's not savvy enough. I don't really know about Django. Anyway like I said your best starting point is to compare the generated HTTP requests using Fiddler (or similar) and play spot the difference, and see what you turn up.

Answer (score 1):

There was a missing component in the HTTP header, it needed to have "cedentials: 'included'"
The final header was :

```
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/habit/?format=json',{
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
       'Accept': '*/*',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': 'Token '+this.authToken.token
     },
     credentials: 'include'
  })
```